# Is there an equivalent of the TokenHelper class written in Java for Sharepoint 2013 OAuth Authentication

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I'm trying to use the following guide to authenticate my (java) app to an internally hosted Sharepoint 2013 site: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj687470.aspx

I've already registered the app and have the client ID and secret. Unfortunately, this method relies heavily on TokenHelper.cs (or .vb), but I'm unable to find a java equivalent that either Microsoft or a 3rd party developer has written.

Any help pointing me in the right direction would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Use the Active Directory Authentication Library. Instructions and libraries are available [here](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-java).

Personally I have used the Android library, and I can say that it works like a charm.